SSPI handshake failure when trying to connect with SSL in Java on JBoss 4.0
I'm having issues with a REST service on my client's testing server. In my local server, the REST POST works perfectly.
Both servers are running Java version 1.8.201 and support TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, and TLSv1.
The exception thrown on the client's server is "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure."
I ran a PowerShell script to check if the server could access the host to which I want to post the service, and it threw this error: "AuthenticateAsClient" with argument 1: Failed to perform a call to SSPI.
Could this difference be leading to the SSLHandshakeException?
Any help is welcome; I'm out of options with this issue.
this is the script;

 $tcpClient = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
$tcpClient.Connect("developer.atlassian.com", 443)
$sslStream = New-Object System.Net.Security.SslStream($tcpClient.GetStream(), $false)
$sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("developer.atlassian.com")

Write-Output "Cipher: $($sslStream.CipherAlgorithm)"
Write-Output "Cipher strength: $($sslStream.CipherStrength)"
Write-Output "SSL protocol: $($sslStream.SslProtocol)"
Write-Output "Is authenticated: $($sslStream.IsAuthenticated)"

$sslStream.Close()
$tcpClient.Close()



Ensured both servers use Java 1.8.201 and support TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, and TLSv1.
Implemented code to accept all certificates and disable hostname verification to rule out certificate issues.
Used PowerShell to test connectivity and SSL/TLS configuration directly from the server, confirming that the server can establish a secure connection using TLSv1.2.
Analyzed and logged cipher suites available on the Java server to ensure compatibility.

Despite these efforts, I continue to encounter the "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure" error when attempting to consume a REST service.
